# Weblogic: limit access to certain resources (URIs) by IP

Tags: linux, weblogic, servlet-filters

community.

Is it possible to limit access to certain URIs (say /myapp/admin/*) based on requester IP on a Weblogic server?
I'd like to allow access only from trusted machines in local network and deny all others BUT only regarding this specific URIs. Other application locations should be accessible for everyone.

The question is, whether it is achievable without development of a separate Filter class?

I found just this in Apache "Location" directive, but sadly no similar stuff in Weblogic.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you accessing WebLogic directly or using a web server in front of WebLogic?

Comment: Directly, and it is clustered if that matters.

Comment: If you were using Apache to front the cluster, the mod_authz_core plugin would do what you need.